# Empty table using XML PATH

Tags: c#, sql-server

At this time I have a new table that is empty and I would like to use FOR XML PATH to build an xml return. In my c# code I have error related to missing root element.

> How would I return XML even if there is no content from the select?

```
SELECT 
[CommitteeSurveryid]
,[GroupId]
,[SurveryTitle]
,[SurveryDate]
,[FileManagerid]
FROM [CommitteSurvery] as cs
WHERE (cs.GroupId = 620)
FOR XML PATH('Items'), ROOT('CommitteeSurveryItem');
```

[[image: SQL[1]]

Comment: Are you sure you have at least one row that has `GroupId = 620`? Because thats your `WHERE` filter. If your table is empty then nothing will show up.

Comment: groupid is the foreign key. in the c# code it will load the result into an xml object inputXML.LoadXml(sXml);

Comment: I would debug in SQL Server Management Studio which give much better errors messages than in c#.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to display an XML even if there is no content from the select, correct? If so please edit the post to clarify this.

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: Why don't you just count the rows matching your `where` clause and return 
 `select cast('<CommitteeSurveryItem/>' as xml)` if row count is 0?

Comment: It can be done in one query without counting: `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT .. FOR XML PATH, TYPE), '<CommitteeSurveryItem/>')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to return the root node `CommitteeSurveryItem`, even when the table is empty or no rows match the `where` clause, you will have to rearrange your code as an XML subquery like this:

```sql
SELECT
  (
    SELECT
      [CommitteeSurveryid]
     ,[GroupId]
     ,[SurveryTitle]
     ,[SurveryDate]
     ,[FileManagerid]
    FROM [CommitteSurvery] as cs
    WHERE (cs.GroupId = 620)
    FOR XML PATH('Items'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('CommitteeSurveryItem');
```

Which returns...

| XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B |
| --- |
| <CommitteeSurveryItem/> |

After inserting some matching row data you will see `Items` child nodes as expected...

```sql
insert dbo.CommitteSurvery (CommitteeSurveryid, SurveryTitle, SurveryTitle, FileManagerid, GroupId) values
  (1, 'Foo', '2021-01-01', 1, 620),
  (2, 'Bar', '2021-01-02', 1, 620);
```

```xml
<CommitteeSurveryItem>
    <Items>
        <CommitteeSurveryid>1</CommitteeSurveryid>
        <GroupId>620</GroupId>
        <SurveryTitle>Foo</SurveryTitle>
        <SurveryDate>2021-01-01</SurveryDate>
        <FileManagerid>1</FileManagerid>
    </Items>
    <Items>
        <CommitteeSurveryid>2</CommitteeSurveryid>
        <GroupId>620</GroupId>
        <SurveryTitle>Bar</SurveryTitle>
        <SurveryDate>2021-01-02</SurveryDate>
        <FileManagerid>1</FileManagerid>
    </Items>
</CommitteeSurveryItem>
```